# differences in ASLR on Linux and Windows

Tags: security

Reflecting on some RE I've done recently I'm curious about how differently ASLR works across Windows and Linux :-

- Is it enough to compile shared libraries on Linux with the fPIC flag so that they can take advantage of the ASLR system wide setting?
- On Windows are there any compile time settings other than ASCOMPAT that I should enable in order to take advantage of ASLR?
- Are there any ways in which the ASLR implementation is better in one platform that the other?

Comment: Closing as Off-Topic (this question is about OS security features, not about reverse engineering)